# How to store website url in session or cookies ?

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

I Have Multi website site.
when site open first time in browser that time show a popup.
popup have Website stores url.

so want if any customer click (website store 1) then he will see only website store 1 not store 2.

if customer type store 2 url manually then also redirect at store 1.

Please Suggest Me.

Comment: Have you use any extension?

Comment: No,  I didn't use any Extension !!!

Comment: I want do this without extension any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, maybe it will work.

After customer choose store to display, save the store code to session

```
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
$cookie->set('store_code', $storeCode, time() + 86400, '/');
```

In `index.php` add this code right before line `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`:

```
Mage::app();
if($cookie->get('store_code')){
    $mageRunCode = $cookie->get('store_code');
}
Mage::reset();
```

This will redirect customer to the store that he chose before.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing data in session

$url = Mage::getBaseUrl();// Your website
Or
   $url = 'www.google.com'; // Any random url

```
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMySession($websiteUrl); //This will set data in the session
    $var = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMySession(); //This will retrive data from session
```